# Visual Studio 2010 Beta start without debugging Console wont stay open

Tags: visual-studio

I want to keep the console (output) window open to view the output of the project I am working on. I have enabled the start without debugging option and added the button to the debugging toolbar, but alas it fails to keep it open nicely like in visual studio 2008. I have to add cin.getline() etc etc etc to get it to stay open, but I don't want to type it. Any suggestions as to alter it Visual Studio 2010 to keep it open, or any debugging tricks to make it easier to view output for longer than a flash. Visual Studio used to have a "Press any key to continue prompt" I want it back...

Comment: Is this Beta 1 or Beta 2? I am using Beta 2, and the "Press any key to continue" prompt does appear, both with C# and C++ console applications.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 release and I think it depends on the linker `/SUBSYSTEM` option. For me if SUBSYSTEM is Console, start without debugging pauses, but if SUBSYSTEM is empty or not set then start without debugging doesn't pause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how useful this would be for large projects, but you could also use

```
system("PAUSE");
```

and then that should keep the console open until you press any key.

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed pressing `ctrl-f5`? it works for me in beta 2.